# How do I solve the following python-scrapy error?

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

It shows no error during execution but i’m getting a blank file output.My  code for spider is as follows:

```
   from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
   from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
   from example.items import exampleItem
   class MySpider(BaseSpider):
   name = "eg"
   allowed_domains = ["timeanddate.com"]
   start_urls = ["https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/"]
   def parse(self, response):
          titles = response.selector.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[8]/section[2]/div[1]/table/tbody")
     items = []
     for titles in titles:
        item = exampleItem()
        item["title"] = titles.xpath("//tr/td[@a]/text()").extract()
        item["link"] = titles.xpath("//tr/td[@class=rbi]").extract()
        items.append(item)
     return items
```

Code for Scraper.item is as follows:

```
    from scrapy.item import Item, Field

    class exampleItem(Item):
    title = Field()
    link = Field()
```

LogFile output is as follows,the only error displayedin this is :
<404 https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/)>: HTTP status code is not 
       handled or not allowed

```
        [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.3.3 started (bot: example)
        [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 
        'example.spiders', 'FEED_URI': 'items.csv', 'SPIDER_MODULES': 
       ['example.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'example', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 
        'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv'}
       [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
       ['scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
       'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
       'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
        'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
        [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
       ['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
       'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
    [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
  ['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
  'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
   'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
   'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
     'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
       [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
       []
       [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
       [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), 
       scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
       [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 
       127.0.0.1:6023
       [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET 
       https://www.timeanddate.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
       [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET 
      https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/)> (referer: None)
   [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response 
   <404 https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/)>: HTTP status code is not 
   handled or not allowed
   [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
   [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
   {'downloader/request_bytes': 456,
    'downloader/request_count': 2,
    'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
    'downloader/response_bytes': 6109,
     'downloader/response_count': 2,
   'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
   'downloader/response_status_count/404': 1,
    'finish_reason': 'finished',
   'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 7, 14, 2, 24, 993404),
      'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
    'log_count/INFO': 8,
    'response_received_count': 2,
    'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
    'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
       'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
     'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
    'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 7, 14, 2, 23, 158763)}
     [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is your `XPath selectors` don't match the page source.

One known issue with webbrowser developer tools is that they show `tbody` elements where no such elements exist in response data. So it's always worth trying not to include them or circumvent them.

Then there are some code problems too. There is a `for titles in titles:`. Looks somehow wrong to me.

Then the XPath statements in the loop also don't match anything with my developer tools. There is no match for `//tr/td[@a]`. It should be `//tr/td[a]`. But the latter one matches *all* anchors at once which makes it difficult to extract single items.

So I tried to rewrite your code and came up with the following:

```py
import scrapy

class MyItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()


class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "eg"
    allowed_domains = ["timeanddate.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/"]

    def parse(self, response):

        for sel_row in response.xpath('//table//tr'):
            for sel_td in sel_row.xpath('./td[a]'):

                item = MyItem()
                item["title"] = sel_td.xpath('./a/text()').extract_first()
                item["link"] = sel_td.xpath('./following::td[@class="rbi"][1]').extract_first()
                yield item
```

This code is tested with `scrapy 1.3.2 / Python 2.7.11`.

Comment: I tried executing this code by "scrapy crawl eg -o items.csv -t csv" command, but it still is giving a blank file as output

Comment: Hmmm ... I get a file with 144 lines. What does the output of the command look like? Any errors?

Comment: No, it doesn't show any errors while executing the command. I have just updated my items.py coding too..

Comment: I just added the item definition I use to the code.

Comment: Puh ... I have no idea why you get a 404. I do not get it.

Comment: I get the output too.. thanks.. :) Actually, I have not removed the other import packages from the coding. Didn't know that it'll effect the coding..My mistake.

Comment: I'm glad it finally works.  Interesting that other imports affect http response!